# Following feed careers job link on android doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, ios-app

When I click a careers link from the feed on the android app the browser opens up with what looks to be a correct url (... /j/ct?cid=...) which then redirects to the careers mobile homepage. I guess the android app should take me straight to the mobile version of the job page when using the phone layout, or the redirect should preserve the whole url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definitely should not be happening. Was just able to repro this from the iOS app. I have a good idea where that's happening, I'll look into that right away.

*EDIT*

Okay we had a small validation issue regarding HTTP referers. The referer coming from the mobile app was being rejected unintentionally. This has been fixed, and should filter down into your mobile feeds shortly.

Comment: I need a clarification: was the issue independent of the mobile's OS? Meaning, regardless iOS or Android, they would be rejected? Reading this Q&A thread at current writing, it's unclear if the issue is exclusive to iOS or Android app.