# Clicking a careers link in android app redirects to main careers site

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, android-app, android-app-feed

I am having a problem that was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248627/following-feed-careers-job-link-on-android-doesnt-work) in February.

If I tap a career listing that is in my feed, it redirects me to the careers main (mobile) page instead of going to the listing itself.

Is this a regression of the previous fix?

I am utilizing the [beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app) app, version 1.0.72

Comment: It was fixed for **iOS app** - the android app is a totally different thing with different code. Its developer would have to write a new fix from scratch.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think they use software to make the app both compatible with iOS and Android with the same code. I know that Telerik offers software to do this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @cybermonkey but I'm 100% sure that there is no code that works the same on iOS and on android. Each OS need its own code, and SE has separate teams working on each of the apps. One app can have feature the other is lacking, and vice versa, e.g. revisions list that was added to the iOS app but still missing in the android app. So this one here is just one of many features/bug fixes that were applied only in one of the apps.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Code is written independently, and the software then converts it and creates the project ready to be signed.

Comment: Strangely, not repro'd on 1.0.72 beta. I got redirected to the job listing. Whether it's been ninja fixed, or it's case-by-case, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  Could be a bug that was fixed either on the server or the client.  No idea.